# How do I make a ggplot of multiple means subsetted by a category?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

So my dataset has a category for which diet the chicks were fed and their weight over time. I figured out how to plot the overall means for weight, but I can't figure out how to plot the means for each individual diet category over time alongside it.

I want to make a graph with means of specific groups alongside the overall mean. This is what I have so far:

```
data("ChickWeight")
ChickWeight <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)

ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, color=Diet))+
  stat_summary(fun="mean", geom="crossbar", color="red")+
  geom_point()
  labs(title= "Chick weight over time", x="Days Since Birth", y="Weight (g)")
```

Unfortunately it doesn't look like using fun.y="mean" is a possible argument for geom_point, much less separating means out by varaible. Ideally I would end up with a scatterplot of only means, with 5 point at each time frame: the overall weight mean, and the weight mean of each of the four diets.

Full disclosure, this is a part of a class assingment, but this is just an additional challenge problem. I've been working on it for a while without a breakthrough so I'm really anxious to figure it out at this point.

Comment: You can just use `fun` instead of `fun.y`

Answer (score 1):

You could do a hack using a code like this. You can use `stat_summary()` twice to include the expected results. Also, if you want some variable being considered in your plot, you have to enable it with `group` option in `aes()`. Here some options:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data
data("ChickWeight")
ChickWeight <- as.data.frame(ChickWeight)

#Code
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, color=Diet))+
  stat_summary(fun.y="mean", geom="crossbar", color="red")+
  stat_summary(data=ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, color=Diet,group=Diet),
               fun.y="mean", geom="crossbar")+
  labs(title= "Chick weight over time", x="Days Since Birth", y="Weight (g)")
```

Output:

[image]

Or if you want a point for overall mean you can try this:

```
#Compute means
ChickWeight %>% group_by(Time) %>% 
  summarise(Mean=mean(weight,na.rm=T)) %>% mutate(Diet=NA) -> means
#Code 2
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, color=Diet))+
  stat_summary(data=ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, color=Diet,group=Diet),
               fun.y="mean", geom="crossbar")+
  geom_point(data=means,aes(x=Time,y=Mean),show.legend = F,color='red')+
  labs(title= "Chick weight over time", x="Days Since Birth", y="Weight (g)")
```

Output:

[image]

And if you want an additional legend with the overall mean, you can use this code:

```
#Compute means 2
ChickWeight %>% group_by(Time) %>% 
  summarise(Mean=mean(weight,na.rm=T)) %>% mutate(Diet=NA,Var='Overall mean') -> means

#Code3
ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, color=Diet))+
  stat_summary(data=ChickWeight, aes(x=Time, y=weight, color=Diet,group=Diet),
               fun.y="mean", geom="crossbar")+
  geom_point(data=means,aes(x=Time,y=Mean,fill=Var),shape=21)+
  labs(title= "Chick weight over time", x="Days Since Birth", y="Weight (g)")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = 'red')
```

Output:

[image]